# Linking PubNub to Angular5 to post data in web-app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, pubnub

I have created a project with Arduino, and I am sending the live data to pubNub via the sub and pub keys and this all works great. I am not trying to get the data to come from PubNub into my Angular5 application.

I have subscribed to the channel like so:

```
  constructor(pubnub: PubNubAngular) {
    pubnub.init({
        publishKey: 'My_pub_key',
        subscribeKey: 'My_sub_key'
        })
        pubnub.subscribe({
          channels: ['MyChannel'],
          triggerEvents: true,
          withPresence: true,
          autoload: 100
      });
    }
```

This is within a component called "pubnub". I then do this to post it to my page in a component called arduino-app:

```
  <div class="col-md-5 bgwhite" *ngIf="!appStart">

    <h3 style="color: red; padding-top:1%;"> Application beginning...</h3>
    <app-pubnub></app-pubnub>
  </div>
```

However the data isn't posting to my app, has anyone done anything with this before? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to get the messages after you have subscribed.

This is how I have it working:

```
  pubnub.subscribe({channels: ['MyChannel'], triggerEvents: true, withPresence: true, autoload: 100});

  this.threads = pubnub.getMessage('MyChannel')
```

Then I can access the messages from `threads`

Also check out https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-angular2 for further documentation.

Comment: It's just a variable, it could be whatever you want. Create a new variable and set it equal to `pubnub.getMessage('MyChannel')` and console.log that variable - you should see the data come through.